# format NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i take the user date from facebook , it look like

> "birthday_date" = "03/04/1987"
>   i wrote this code

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:birthDate];

    NSLog(@"dateformstring %@ ",dateFromString);
    [birthPicker setDate:dateFromString animated:YES];
```

and the result date from string si : 1988-12-25 23:00:00 +0000 , i have this date selected in the picker , I do not know where did this date :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];`

Answer (score 2):

oops. As tilo said, use "yyyy." As mentioned in the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html):

*"A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of "Week of Year"), used in the ISO year-week calendar."*

Answer (score 0):

Made an **NSString extension** for that.

```
// Simple as this.   
date = dateString.dateValue;
```

Thanks to [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it recognizes a whole lot of format.

```
// Tested in GMT+1 (Hungary).
@"2014-01-16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014.01.16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014/01/16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014 Jan 16" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"2014 Jan 16th" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"20140116" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01-16-2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01.16.2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01/16/2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"16 January 2014" dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
@"01-16-2014 17:05:05" dateValue is <2014-01-16 16:05:05 +0000>
@"01-16-2014 T 17:05:05 UTC" dateValue is <2014-01-16 17:05:05 +0000>
@"17:05, 1 January 2014 (UTC)" dateValue is <2014-01-01 16:05:00 +0000>
```

Part of [eppz!kit](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit), grab the category [NSString+EPPZKit.h](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit/blob/master/eppz!kit/NSString%2BEPPZKit.h) from GitHub.