# How to init a NSDate with a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

I'm still beginner at obj-C/iOS development... I've created a class containing a `NSDate *date`, and I get the data from a XML file. So I want to do something like this :

```
[myItem setDate:[NSDate dateWithString:xmlDate]];
```

I get the error :

> No known class method for selector 'dateWithString:'

What is the best way to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a `NSDateFormatter` instance for this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// set the appropriate format in this string
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:xmlDate];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 4):

You need an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter). See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352487/nsdate-from-nsstring) or [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332319/convert-nsstring-of-a-date-to-an-nsdate) or [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420351/format-nsstring-to-nsdate) or just the [Apple Date Formatter guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) for more details.

<sub>And please remember to search for duplicate questions before posting.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

To make an `NSDate` object from a `NSString` you should use `NSDateFormatter`. More info can be found on Apple's website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope it helps